# About "PUT" and "DELETE" query

Tags: loopbackjs

I just started using loopback and I have 'Profile' model in which addresses are embedded
{

"addresses":
 [{

"type": "office",
            "street": "2",
            "city": "Noida",
            "state": "UP",
            "country": "india",
            "zipCode": "201301",
            "id": "b6268532-96a9-427e-87a5-df04750af2a0"
        },

{
            "type": "home",
            "street": "1",
            "city": "Noida",
            "state": "UP",
            "country": "india",
            "zipCode": "201301",
            "id": "6812b958-afb2-4e91-bdde-0977545c2e46"
        }
    ]

}

this is an array of address and i want to delete the record of "id:6812b958-afb2-4e91-bdde-0977545c2e46" and update the record of "id:b6268532-96a9-427e-87a5-df04750af2a0".
Used methods like destroyById, updateById,remove,updateAttributes and updateAll but nothing worked.
How can i perform this?
i am using loopback with mongodb.

[code for delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYLSi.png)

[code for update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOme8.png)

what is wrong in this code? and which other methods can be used instead?
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: can you show some code? Otherwise it will be hard to guess what you're doing wrong

Comment: added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. You need to provide **id** with the **url** in '**delete**' request.
For Example:

```
                var req = url + "/" + id
                //url is your loopback endpoint url like api/user
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'delete',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    contentLength: "0",
                    url: req,
                    //data: id,
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (response) {
                       //your function after deleting record
                    }
                });
```

Hope it works!